# 「〜ている」Sentence Translation

Tags: translation, て-form, aspect

When you have a phrase like,

> 起きたばかりでまだなにも食べていない。

does it feel more like

"I just woke up, so I haven't eaten anything yet" ?

or

"I just woke up, so I'm not eating anything yet".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The former. For the vast majority of verbs and situations I can think of, it is:

> まだ [ te-form verb ] いない
>   *I haven't [ past participle ] yet*

- まだ髪が乾いていない *My hair hasn't dried yet*
- その本はまだ読んでいない *I haven't read that book yet*
- まだ聴いていない曲 *A song I haven't heard yet*

---

*I'm not [ present participle ] yet* can be expressed with something like:

> まだ [ verb stem ] はじめていない

So for example, まだ何も食べはじめていない (literally *I haven't started eating yet*) is closer to *I'm not eating anything yet*.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is correct:
"I just woke up, so I haven't eaten anything yet"

For "I just woke up, so I'm not eating anything yet", it should be 
起きたばかりなのでまだ食べない